# How to fetch files by mime type with wget

Tags: wget, mime-types

Some URLs are like this:

```
/foo/bar
```

In that, they don't have an extension like this:

```
/foo/bar.txt
```

If there is an extension it's easy:

```
wget -r -A .txt http://asdf.com
```

But if there isn't, then I'm not sure how to fetch the files. Basically, there are some files like PDFs or other things that are at a path like `/0du8qj8quqjc9` with no extension, or maybe even `/download.php?pdf=124u0cje8u`. The question is how to download these files *only if it matches a mime-type*. So for example something like:

```
wget -r --accept-mime text/plain,application/pdf http://asdf.com
```

Wondering if there's anything to do like that.

Answer (score 2):

Wget2 already has this feature :-)

```
--filter-mime-type    Specify a list of mime types to be saved or ignored`

### `--filter-mime-type=list`

Specify a comma-separated list of MIME types that will be downloaded.  Elements of list may contain wildcards.
If a MIME type starts with the character '!' it won't be downloaded, this is useful when trying to download
something with exceptions. For example, download everything except images:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=*,\!image/*

It is also useful to download files that are compatible with an application of your system. For instance,
download every file that is compatible with LibreOffice Writer from a website using the recursive mode:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=$(sed -r '/^MimeType=/!d;s/^MimeType=//;s/;/,/g' /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop)
```

Wget2 has not been released as of today, but will be soon. Debian unstable already has an alpha version shipped.

Look at https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2 for more info. You can post questions/comments directly to bug-wget@gnu.org.